# mysql database not updated

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Or TextBox3.Text = Nothing Or TextBox4.Text = Nothing Or TextBox5.Text = Nothing Or ComboBox1.SelectedItem = Nothing Or ComboBox2.SelectedItem = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("User not updated! Please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else

            mysqlconn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = mysqlconn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE user SET `Firstname` = @fname, `Lastname` = @lname, `Password` = @pword, `contactno` = @contact, `Username` = @uname, `Subject` = @subject, `Position` = @post, `Gender` = @gender WHERE `ID` = @id"
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@ID", "ID")
                .AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox3.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@fname", TextBox1.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@lname", TextBox2.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@pword", TextBox4.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@contact", TextBox5.Text)
                .AddWithValue("@subject", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
                .AddWithValue("@post", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
                If RadioButton1.Checked Then
                    .AddWithValue("@gender", "Male")
                ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
                    .AddWithValue("@gender", "Female")
                End If
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            MsgBox("Product Updated Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

            mysqlconn.Close()
```

is there anything wrong with my code ? it is not updating my database. but the messagebox says that product is updated successfully without error.

Comment: Most likely the copy to output folder option for the database in your project is set to always.  In which case the data is being saved, but the database is being over written with the old one every time you run your app.  Set the option to the best suited option.

Comment: `Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you if the code is changing any rows in the db.  You should never, ever store passwords as plain text

Comment: Do you get any errors? You should wrap a `Try() Catch()` around it.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I don't get any error and at the same time it doesn't update my db

Comment: Can you run that update query in MySQL directly?

Comment: your query is likely wrong -  `.AddWithValue("@ID", "ID")` will only update a record with an id of `"ID"` which seems very unlikely.  `Add` should be used rather than `AddWithValue` for a myriad of reasons

Comment: In common, ID is an integer auto increment. But you use it for a constant string named "ID". Please replace .AddWithValue with .Add. Write `ID` instead of `"ID"` and it should work